# Как использовать window.onload в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Изучаю react. Хочу вывести комментарии, хранящиеся в localStorage при загрузке страницы, но не соображу, как это сделать. Пробовал скопировать массив из состояния и закинуть в него всё, что есть в сторожке так:

```
window.onload = function() {
        const initialItems = [...items] 

        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            initialItems.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(items.itemId)));
        }

        setItems(items);
    };
```

Код компонента:

```
import CommentForm from './CommentForm'
import CommentList from './CommentList'
import CommentatorsTop from "./CommentatorsTop";
import {useState} from 'react';

function CommentWidget() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    
    window.onload = function() {
        const initialItems = [...items]

        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            initialItems.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(items.itemId)));
        }

        setItems(items);
    };

    function addItem(item) {
        const newItems = [...items]

        newItems.push(item)

        setItems(newItems);

        const storageNewItems = JSON.stringify(newItems);

        localStorage.setItem(item.itemId, storageNewItems);
    }

    function removeCommentItem(position, itemId) {
        if (window.confirm('Удалить?')) {
            const newListItem = [...items]

            newListItem.splice(position, 1);

            localStorage.removeItem(itemId);

            setItems(newListItem);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="CommentWidget">
            <div className="CommentForm-wrap">
                <CommentForm addNewItem={addItem}/>

                <CommentList comments={items} removeCommentItem={removeCommentItem} />
            </div>

            <CommentatorsTop names={items}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CommentWidget;
```

[Весь код здесь](https://github.com/iliyasold/commentsWidget)

Что я тут делаю не так?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Нашёл ошибку в функции addItem: отправлять в localStorage здесь следует элемент item, а не массив, конечно.
2. Однозначно, здесь можно использовать, хук useEffect. Однако, поскольку вопрос касался именно window.onload оставлю здесь решение. При перезагрузке страницы копировать массив items не нужно и бессмысленно. Необходимо объявить пустой массив
   `const storageItems = []` и добавить в него всё, что есть в localStorage так: `for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) { storageItems.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)))); }` и затем передать массив в state: `setItems(items);`

В итоге компонент выглядит так:

```
import CommentForm from './CommentForm'
import CommentList from './CommentList'
import CommentatorsTop from "./CommentatorsTop";
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function CommentWidget() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    window.onload = function () {
        const storageItems = []

        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            storageItems.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))));
        }

        setItems(storageItems);
    };

    function addItem(item) {
        const newItems = [...items]

        newItems.push(item)

        setItems(newItems);

        const storageNewItems = JSON.stringify(item);

        localStorage.setItem(item.itemId, storageNewItems);
    }

    function removeCommentItem(position, itemId) {
        if (window.confirm('Удалить?')) {
            const newListItem = [...items]

            newListItem.splice(position, 1);

            localStorage.removeItem(itemId);

            setItems(newListItem);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="CommentWidget">
            <div className="CommentForm-wrap">
                <CommentForm addNewItem={addItem}/>

                <CommentList comments={items} removeCommentItem={removeCommentItem}/>
            </div>

            <CommentatorsTop names={items}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CommentWidget;
```

Answer (score 5):

https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
Вам нужен хук UseEffect. Он отслеживает перерендеринг компонента и вызывает функцию, которая выполняется, когда компонент рендерится. Если у этой функции будет return, то во время уничтожения компонента выполнится код из этого return.

Так вот, первым параметром UseEffet принимает функцию, вторым - массив зависимостей. Если второй параметр не будет передан, то функция переданная UseEffect будет вызываться при каждом перерендеринге. Если в качестве параметра будет передан пустой массив, то функция отработает лишь один раз, при первом рендеринге компонента. В качестве элемента этого массива может быть какое-нибудь состояние, например, или любая другая зависимость. Суть в том, что когда это, например, состояние будет изменено, тогда вызовится функция из UseEffect. Аналагом window.onload будет UseEffect со вторым параметром пустым массивов (выполнить при первом рендеринге компонента). Замените блок с

```
 window.onload = function() {
```

на что-то следующее

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
......
useEffect(() => {
const initialItems = [...items]

        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            initialItems.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(items.itemId)));
        }

        setItems(items);
  
}, []);
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас, буду пробовать!)